# Unitary operator on infinite Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis

I am in search of
1) find an example of non identity unitary operator on an infinite dimensional Hilbert space.
2)Prove that the identity operator on an infinite dimensional Hilbert space is not compact.

I have found identity unitary operator on an finite Hilbert space but I am unable to construct example asked in (1). 
Both the questions here are on infinite dimensional Hilbert space so need help.

Comment: Consider $L^2(T)$ where $T$ is the unit circle in the complex plane. Define $(Uf)(z)=f(e^{i\theta}z)$. $U$ is a unitary operator on $L^2(T)$.

Answer (score 2):

See [shift operators](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_operator), like the left shift operator acting on two-sided sequences by $$(x_k)_{k=-\infty }^{\infty }\to (x_{k+1})_{k=-\infty }^{\infty } $$...

Answer (score 2):

You can construct unitary operations on an infinite complex Hilbert space in the following way:

1. Choose some Hilbert space basis.
2. For each vector $b$ in that basis, choose an arbitrary angle $\phi(b)$.
3. Your unitary transformation now is the linear transformation which multiplies each of the basis vectors with $\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\phi(b)}$

**Edit:** I've just came across my old answer and noticed that there was a second part of the question that I didn't address (nor did the other answer to the question):

> 2)Prove that the identity operator on an infinite dimensional Hilbert space is not compact.

Consider an orthonormal basis of the Hilbert space. It is easy to check that any two vectors of that basis have the mutual distance $\sqrt{2}$, which allows to easily check that the basis forms a closed, bounded but not compact set.

Now by definition, an operator is closed if the closure of the image of a bounded set has a relatively compact image, that is, the closure of the image is compact.

Now since the basis forms a bounded set, therefore for the identity to be compact, the image would have to be relatively compact. But the image under the identity is the basis itself, and being a closed set, so is the closure of that image. But we already have seen that this is not a compact set, therefore the identity cannot be a compact operator.